# C# perform methods in a Form

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

How can I create a program in C# that does the following:
 1. Create a WindowsForm with a button and a label
 2. When the button is pressed the label should change from "False" to "True" or vice-versa

I want the label's message to be displayed depending on the state of a boolean variable.

```
bool Light1 = false;
```

When I press the button, I want `Light1` to become True and if I press it again it should become False.

The label shows a **True** or **False** message depending on `Light1`;

The problem I am facing is changing the label depending on `Light1`. The code that gets executed when I press the button is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (parametri.Light1 == false)
    {
        parametri.Light1 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        parametri.Light1 = false;
    }
}
```

`parametri` is a class that contains one public bool `Light1` variable that is initialized to False.

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how I could make the connection between a label and the Light1 variable.

Comment: If you're just getting into C#, you should work on learning WPF and MVVM for UI related development.

Comment: @JordanKaye I think MVVM might be a bit too complicated when OP hasn't had much experience with C#.

Comment: @keyboardP Learning in the wrong way in the first place is only going to complicate things down the road. Better to do things right the first time.

Comment: @JordanKaye I disagree. I think you should have a grasp of the language first before worrying about learning patterns. I agree MVVM is a good pattern, but only if the project is suited to it. It's not as black and white as the "right way" and the "wrong way" IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // No need of IF Statements to reverse a Boolean
    parametri.Light1 = !parametri.Light1;
    label1.Text = parametri.Light1.ToString();
}
```

If you want to have the first letter in uppercase (True, False), just do that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // No need of IF Statements to reverse a Boolean
    parametri.Light1 = !parametri.Light1;

    Char[] characters = parametri.Light1.ToString().ToCharArray();
    characters[0] = Char.ToUpper(characters[0]);

    label1.Text = new String(characters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have another question:

Is it possible to change the label outside the button1_Click scope?
Say, something along the lines of:

    `if(parametri.Light1 == false)  
    label1.Text = "False";  
    else label1.Text = "True";`  

and this code would be put somewhere in the main maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the bool value in a label by the `Text` property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // invert the bool value with the not operator. In C# is equals Java "!"
    parametri.Light1 == !parametri.Light1;

    // print the bool value in your label.
    Label1.Text = parametri.Light1.ToString();
}
```